# SharePoint 2013 update panel does not work

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, updatepanel, sharepoint-2013

I can use an update panel in SharePoint 2010 and Visual Studio 2010, but when I try to use an update panel in SharePoint 2013 and Visual Studio 2012 it does not work. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: You need to provide a little bit more info... :) Do you get an exception? If yes, what does it say? How is your code looking?

Comment: I dont get an exception. My page get refresed when it happens. As I researched, it is about conflict between sharepoint's js and update panels js. I still could not find how to solve it